# Why is a square wave used for audio power calculations?

Tags: amplifier, audio, sound, power-amplifier

I am trying to read this [datasheet](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/data-sheet/TDF8546_SDS.pdf) (NXP TDF8546 Class AB Power Amplifier). On page 12, the power calculations are mentioned as

> Po(max): RL = 4 Ohm, Vp = 14.4V, Vi = 2 V RMS Square wave

As far as I know, while calculating power calculations for any power amplifiers, engineers typically consider the sine wave. The reason I know is, its fundamental signal, and harsh input for power amplifier.

Why NXP considered square wave instead of sine wave in this datasheet?

Comment: A warm welcome to the site. Please can you add IC details and a diagram rather than just a link. If your link breaks in future, the question is meaningless. Thanks.

Comment: I couldn't find (CTRL-F) the term "2RMS" anywhere in the linked document - copy and paste the section you refer to.

Comment: Sorry, typo error. "2 V RMS". Corrected it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because a square wave is the waveform with a given amplitude that produces the maximum amount of power.

Comment: Hi Jakob, any proof or calculations or article which support the answer? Please help.

Comment: You really need proof on that? It's apparent from the waveform itself. Try to think of a waveform that produces more power with same amplitude, and you find none.

Comment: Ok understood. In this case,  When I have to use either Sine or Square wave signals as input test signals?

Comment: I'd just use a sine wave as it is simpler and more pleasant to listen to.

Comment: Usually you just want to measure voltage instead of listening, perhaps using pure resistance or simulated speaker with inductor and resistor. The waveform selection would depend on what you want to measure.

Comment: Please can you expand considerably on this one-line answer, for the benefit of future readers. Thanks.

Comment: square wave output can blow out speakers ... a cheap low power amplifier, overdriven into clipping, has been known to blow out high power speakers